# How to use the Method Create Element (JS) in another PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, menu, off-canvas-menu

I copied a mobile menu from "https://www.100percent.com/" (mobile version). My HTML local page it works fine, but when I put the code in the PHP "header.php", the solution does not work completely.

The DIV that contains the Drawer Is Visible is not created and does not appear.

The site is "https://m.intensebikeshop.com.br".

These pictures show the difference.

A: [My PHP page online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC095.png)

B: [My local HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvO8m.png)

The method create 2 divs before `</body>`, but this tag is the footer.php file. Maybe this is the problem I am not sure.

My page is composed by 3 files (header, home-page and footer.php).

I tried using the z-index. But I think the problem is the method. I see the JS file is not creating the DIVs.

The JS file is: [Theme file JS](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0042/0190/6234/t/103/assets/theme.js?v=3967344447241294827)

Comment: You need to show us some code snippet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [**Question Checklist**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/). Your question should include details of *what you have tried so far*, and include your *relevant code* in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we have the information we need to be able to help.